# Disable save image pop-up on iPad1 and ios5 issue

Tags: ios, css, ipad

I build a mobile website and I have a javascript game on the site that requires user to tap and hold on an image to shake and animate.

I've implemented the following CSS on the image:

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
pointer-events:none;
```

It works fine on ipad2 and ipad3 that runs on ios4 and ios6 but it doesn't work on ipad1 that runs on ios5.

It's hard to believe that the CSS works on ios4 but not on ios5. I doubt this is device specific issue, but let me know if it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was actually very simple to solve. The image i had was actually inside a div container. I have specified the width and height of the image but it actually didn't expand the div container. Therefore the tap and hold events that were bound to the div did not work. The fix was very simple, I just added the height and width for the div.

It's funny because the div was not an issue in ios4 and 6 before this fix implemented.